# Multiplication for a 3d array and slicing

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix of size 5 x 98 x 3. I want to find the transpose of each block of 98 x 3 and multiply it with itself to find the standard deviation. 
Hence, I want my final answer to be of the size 5 x 3 x 3.
What would be an efficient way of doing this using numpy.

I can currently do this using the following code:

```
MU.shape[0] = 5
rows = 98
SIGMA = []
    for i in np.arange(MU.shape[0]):
        SIGMA.append([])
        SIGMA[i] = np.matmul(np.transpose(diff[i]),diff[i])
    SIGMA = np.array(SIGMA)
    SIGMA = SIGMA/rows
```

Here diff is of the size 5 x 98 x 3.

Comment: diff is just the difference between dataset and mean value. MU is the mean value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.einsum` to sum-reduce the last axes off against each other -

```
SIGMA = np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ikl',diff,diff)
SIGMA = SIGMA/rows
```

Use `optimize` flag with `True` value in `np.einsum` to leverage `BLAS`.

We can also use `np.matmul` to get those `sum-reductions` -

```
SIGMA = np.matmul(diff.swapaxes(1,2),diff)
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Although, I will have to read the einsum function in detail.

Comment: @Divakar: +1. Nice to get introduced to `np.einsum()`. Will have to read up on that to understand how "Einstein sum" fits here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
my_result = arr1.swapaxes(1,2) @ arr1
```

**Testing it out:**

```
import numpy as np

NINETY_EIGHT = 10
arr1 = np.arange(5*NINETY_EIGHT*3).reshape(5,NINETY_EIGHT,3)

my_result = arr1.swapaxes(1,2) @ arr1
print (my_result.shape)
```

**Output:**

```
(5, 3, 3)
```

Comment: There is no multiplication happening here. I want to account for that too

Comment: Your requirement mentioned matrix multiplication. The `@` operator performs matrix multiplication.

Comment: Looking at the other answer which you have accepted, I suspect I may have misunderstood your question. I thought your requirement was just to perform the multiplication part. Did you also want the code to calculate differences, means, etc.? Or is it already calculated and stored in `arr1` of shape `(5,98,3)`?

Comment: I have already calculated the difference. I was just having problem with the multiplication part. Also, I didn't exactly know that @ operator performs the mutliplication. Thank you for that. I will try your method as well

Comment: @AhmedJunaidKhalid `@` is same as matmul , specific to Python 3.x. More info - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html